# How to get data from XSD file

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have an [XML schema file](http://pastebin.com/UzN8WnD3).  I want to use Java to open this file, find all elements, extract their names, and write them to a text file.  I have tried various libraries, but I could not get this to work.  Please suggest any libraries or other methods that will work.

Comment: Please show what you tried, and show how it failed.

Answer (score 1):

XSD files are XML files so you can use any suitable XML processing library to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll find a library that exists for your purpose, you'll have to write one yourself. The XSD is simply an XML file that conform to the schema:

Traverse the file as normal using DOM or SAX or whatever your preference is.

Comment: Sir if you have time please my examples. And help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925525/after-getting-complextype-parse-it-also-elements-and-sequences

Comment: You haven't said what technology you are using, e.g. Java, XPath etc. Since you are clearly a novice, it seems unlikely that an example will help you unless we know what technologies you are comfortable with. In fact, I doubt they will help you anyway: I think you need to read a couple of books on XML, then you won't have a problem.

Comment: Sorry Forget , I write with Java. I can get complex types , but can not get child elements

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for the information conveyed by the XML Schema. I would recommend you the [XSOM](http://xsom.java.net/) library, it takes away dealing with the XML itself; nonetheless, a basic understanding of what can be described by an XSD is most likely required.

Follow the [user guide](http://xsom.java.net/userguide.html), there are some examples showing how to move towards what you need.